Custom date range in SQL
I am trying to add a date range to my sql query.
The date range should change every quarter
Example on April 1 2024 - The date range for the data should be trailing 12 months, ie it should look at  01 April 2023 to 30 March 2024 data.
This date range of (01 April 2023 to 30 March 2024) should remain constant until the quarter finishes i.e. up to 01 July 2024.
On 01 July 2024 the date range should automatically update to (01 July 2023 to 30 June 2024).
I do not want to hardcode these dates in the query, can this be automated ?

Just apply the date functions available in your DBMS. E.g.:
select *
from mytable
where mydate < date_trunc('quarter', current_date)
  and mydate >= add_months(date_trunc('quarter', current_date), -12)
order by mydate;

Docs:

Summary of Date and time functions - Amazon Redshift
CURRENT_DATE function - Amazon Redshift
DATE_TRUNC function - Amazon Redshift
ADD_MONTHS function - Amazon Redshift


What does -13 do in the query ? I wanted to look at trailing 12 months, not sure I understand what -13 would do, should it not be -12 ?

@Pratikp: Yes, of course it must be -12. I've corrected this in my answer. Thank you.

Please try this query to get expected result. This is the PostgreSQL query:
select
  date(date_trunc('quarter', CURRENT_DATE  - INTERVAL '1 year' )) as start_date, 
  date(date_trunc('quarter', CURRENT_DATE ) - interval '1 day') as end_date;

